# Mapping spaCy int attributes to string (unicode) attributes

Tags: spacy

For many token properties, such as part of speech and dependency relations, spaCy stores both integer and string attributes. For example, for POS there is `pos_` (string like "PUNCT" and "ADJ") and `pos` (integer values) attributes. The full list of token attributes is [here](https://spacy.io/api/token#attributes).

Is there a convenient way to directly convert between the two representations? Concretely, if I have a POS integer value, is there a way to know what is the corresponding string?

I ran into this issue when using the `count_by` API (see [here](https://spacy.io/api/doc#count_by)), which counts attribute frequencies and returns a dictionary of integer attribute and its counting. An example:

```
>>> doc = nlp("I like natural language processing.")
>>> doc.count_by(spacy.attrs.POS)
{96: 1, 99: 1, 83: 1, 91: 2, 94: 1}
```

Is it possible to get the corresponding string for each POS key?

Of course, there are other ways to get this counting, using the string attributes. But my question is more general than this example application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a lookup table at `doc.vocab.strings`. You can lookup either a string value or its hash with e.g. `doc.vocab.strings["VERB"]` or `doc.vocab.strings[VERB]`. If you have a string and want the hash, use the `spacy.strings.get_string_id()` function. Hashing the string is stateless, so you don't need the `StringStore` for it.

The built-in symbols can also be dereferenced using the `spacy.attrs.IDS` and `spacy.symbols.IDS` global variables.

Comment: Thank you so much!